# To develope a list of unique names with sysdate

Tags: awk, sed

I Have a file with ID’s and Names applicable to them as below:

```
1234|abc|cde|fgh
5678|ijk|abc|lmn
9101|cde|fgh|klm
1213|klm|abc|cde
```

I need a file with only **unique Names** as a list.

Output File:

```
abc|sysdate
cde|sysdate
fgh|sysdate
ijk|sysdate
lmn|sysdate
klm|sysdate
```

Where sysdate is the current timestamp of processing.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52868423/text-processing-to-create-a-list-of-unique-ids

Comment: @Vandhana what are these `sysdate`? actual dates? just string called `sysdate`? Please clarify?

Comment: @Goro its actual date... not just the word

Comment: If it is actual date what it is? is itr the same date in all lines? where it came from. please clarify the question nobody can speculate what in your head~?

Comment: Are all lines of the input file in this exact format, with a 4-digit ID followed by 3 3-letter names?

Comment: @JigglyNaga nope.. they ll be of different format

Comment: @Goro its the actual date. we need to have the current timestamp of processing the data. we need to load with current timestamp.

Comment: @Vandhana not clear, when you say "CURRENT" what do you mean? today? tomorrow? which time stamp? are these `sysdate` the same? all these questions are important to answer your question. Please add more clarifications! thanks!

Comment: Saying they'll be "of different format" doesn't help much.  Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/476222/edit) to include more detail.  How different might it be?  Do you have some example lines that show this other format?

Comment: its relative path of an hyperlink...

Comment: @Vandhana What is "relative path of a hyperlink"?  Was that in reply to an earlier comment (which comment?), or were you adding detail about some part of the original problem (which part?)?  Your question needs to be complete and understandable by itself, without referring to the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cut -f2- -d\| file.txt | tr \| '\n' | sort -u | sed 's/$/|sysdate/'
```

- `cut` extracts columns from the input, `-d` tells it what delimiter to use, `-f` specifies which columns we want. So, here we extract every column starting from 2 using `|` as the delimiter, it needs to be backslashed as `|` has a special meaning in the shell
- `tr` transliterates, i.e. replaces all `|`'s with newlines
- `sort -u` sorts and throws out duplicates
- `sed` `s///` is substitution, here it replaces the end of line (`$`) with `|sysdate`

To include the actual date, just change the last entry to

```
sed 's/$/|'"$(date)"/
```

where `$()` is command substitution which replaces the command with its output.

Comment: Thank u so much.... I am getting word sysdate,but instead i need actual date.. how to achieve this.

Comment: @Vandhana: Check the update.

Comment: Thank u... `sed 's/$/|'"$(date)"/` worked.. u had missed |... is there any way to get only date without time?

Comment: @Vandhana: See `man date` for all the possible output formats. Something like `date +%F` maybe?